# What does "net ex yard" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I asked a timber supplier to quote some piles. He provided prices and added:

> Both prices are **net ex yard** <place name>

Googling does not help much, but I found a few other examples, like [this](https://www.donedeal.co.uk/heating-for-sale/top-quality-firewood-for-sale/29391035):

> Top Quality dry Firewood for sale
>
> 80 nets per pallet
>
> £1.80 per **net ex yard**
>
> 50 pallets available for immediate delivery.

I presume that means the stuff is available for pick up at their yard at that price i.e. no delivery included.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your intuition is correct, "ex yard" is being used to mean "this is the price *to pick them up outside the yard [location] where they currently are*" (i.e. **not** the price to have them delivered to your desired location).

Googling the term "ex yard," the first result is [this Investopedia entry on the term "ex works"](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/exw.asp) which means that exactly. My guess is that "ex yard" and "ex works" are interchangeable here.

"Net" is used in a different way in your other example; there it is a noun meaning "some specific amount of firewood," presumably bundled in a a physical net. The advertisement says there are 80 *nets* per pallet and the price is £1.80 per net (or £144.00 per pallet). In your question ["net" is an adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/net#Adjective):

> 3. Remaining after expenses or deductions. ***net** profit; **net** weight*
> 4. Final; end. ***net** result; **net** conclusion*

So "net ex yard" thus means "total price, all included, assuming you pick them up yourself."